# How to describe Risk levels in cognito adaptive authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

How adaptive authentication for sign-in attempts rated as low, medium and high risk?

Comment: Can someone tell me what type of attempts makes High level risk, what type of attempts makes Medium level risk and low level risk.

Comment: What do you mean by "attempts"? What type of "risk"?

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, we want know how these risks are calculated, and what is the definition for each risk level?
What type of login actions causes Lower risk, and what type of login actions causes High risk?

Comment: I think these aren't public for a very good reason - security